# Prove that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} =\overline{ \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f :\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ has all its first partial derivatives defined at any
point in the open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$, then at that point  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} =\overline{ \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}}$$

Let $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$

Then, $\overline{f(z)} = u(x,y) - i v(x,y)$

I know that $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) $ and $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) $

Also, $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = u_x + i v_x = v_y - iu_y$

How can I use this to prove the equation above?

Comment: Do you actually know what $\frac12\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ means in terms on $u$ and $v$?

Comment: @Gae.S. I know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}  = u_x + i v_x = v_y - i u_x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
f=u+iv
$$
then
$$
\overline f=u-iv\;.
$$
Since
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z}
=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
$$
you get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \overline f}{\partial\overline z}
&=\frac12\left(u_x-iv_x+iu_y+v_y\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\overline f_x+i \overline f_y\right)\\
&=\overline{\frac12\left(f_x- if_y\right)}\\
&=\overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}
\end{align*}
as wanted.